# Maven plugin not failing for C++ build error

Tags: c++, maven

I am using

```
org.codehaus.mojo - exec-maven-plugin
```

to build my C++ project. Below is the `pom` for the same. Attempting to use a normal `make` using GCC is throwing an error, but if I do

```
mvn clean install
```

using maven, it is building successfully, although it is throwing an error in the console.

This is a part of my code:

[image]